# Rename file names with a parent directory name

Tags: find, rename, mv, cp

I want to rename my files recursively, ending with *.fna.gz with the parent directory two-step-up i.e. "Aspergillus_neoniger". You can see the subdirectories details in this image

[tree command image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEEm3.png)

```
.
├── Aaosphaeria_arxii
│   ├── all_assembly_versions
│   │   └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1
│   │       ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_assembly_structure
│   │       ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz
│   │       ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_genomic.fna.gz
│   │       └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_rna_from_genomic.fna.gz
│   ├── latest_assembly_versions
│   │   └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1
│   │       ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_assembly_structure
│   │       ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz
│   │       ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_genomic.fna.gz
│   │       └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_rna_from_genomic.fna.gz
│   └── representative
│       └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1
│           ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_assembly_structure
│           ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz
│           ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_genomic.fna.gz
│           └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_rna_from_genomic.fna.gz
```

I didn't post the output of "tree" because it was not being seen in a proper format after posting.
Every scientific name "Aaosphaeria_arxii" has three sub-directories, i just want to extract files from "latest_assembly_versions" folder with "_genomic.fna.gz" extension. And rename *"_genomic.fna.gz" with the scientific name "Aaosphaeria_arxii" in this case.

Regards

Comment: Tell your teacher that using directory- and filenames like `GCA_003.asdkfa1.whatever_fancystring.9976asdf.gz` will not make any student a better coder. Such examples, if anything, can only make these exercises look terrible. Better crafted, more human-oriented examples would not threaten crushing your interest in this topic: such way you, students, could even realize that solving these exercises can be **exciting and fun**. But the key to that is that you dig up the steps of the solution yourself, web-searching each step of the way. But before that: _ask for more enjoyable homework_.

Comment: ... and 10 years on in real life you find out that this kind of thing is not what you like ;-) Better to find it out now @Levente :D :D

Comment: @Levente those are very common and standard names in bioinformatics. Nothing extreme or unusual about them, I deal with file names like that every day. If those are homework examples, then they are particularly well selected ones to make them realistic. I don't know why you think this is homework, by the way.

Comment: shahzad, please don't post images of text. Instead, use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) and post the file names (ideally, the output of `tree`) directly into your question so we can easily see it and copy it. Please [edit] your question, include the example file/directory names and also show us how you want them to be renamed. We can't help you rename them if you don't tell us what to rename them to.

Comment: @terdon The mental emphasis should be getting a grasp on bash first, which is not a beginner-friendly beast in the first place. When one has gotten the hang of it, then as a next stage, they could introduce realistic working subjects. But at this point, in my opinion, it's just a bad distraction, a bad waste of cognitive capacity, and a failure at preserving or even nurturing passion for this trade.

Comment: @Levente why do you think the OP is a student, what makes you think this is homework? And, even if it is homework, why would it be from a course teaching bash and not a course on bioinformatics? Finally, what is it that makes these files difficult? There are no spaces, no special characters, nothing to be handled here. Anything that would work for a file called `foo` will also work for a file called `GCA_003184625.1_Aspneo1_rna_from_genomic.fna.gz`.

Comment: till now, i have used "find ../fungi/ -name *genomic.fna.gz" to extract all the file names with complete path, and now i want to use | and mv to move those files 2 directories up. but mv is not supporting the recursive option

Comment: @shahzad sure but it is not mv that needs to do that... find feeds its results to mv one at a time so mv does not need to be recursive ;-)

Comment: thank you @rinzwind, for editing my question, sorry i just edited it to add something and its now in previous form again.

Comment: @shahzad yeah I was f5-ing and it went from good to bad :D :D

Comment: That is a completely different question. Please [edit] your question as I asked and i) show us the output of `tree` so we can set up something similar on our machines for testing and ii) show us what the final output you are expecting is.

Comment: Still waiting on @terdon to post an answer >:DDDD DAMN! He posted in between :+

Comment: I am waiting to see an example of the final name so I know what to do!

Comment: "Aaosphaeria_arxii_genomic.fna.gz"

Comment: "GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1" NEEDS TO BE CHANGED IN TO "Aaosphaeria_arxii"

Comment: @shahzad please ***[edit]*** your question and show us. You have three .fna files per directory, we need to see how you want each of them to be renamed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `rename` command:

```
rename 's|((.+?)/.*/)(.*)|$1$2_$3|' */*/*/*fna.gz
```

**Before:**

```
$ tree
.
└── Aaosphaeria_arxii
    ├── all_assembly_versions
    │   └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1
    │       ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_assembly_structure
    │       ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz
    │       ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_genomic.fna.gz
    │       └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_rna_from_genomic.fna.gz
    ├── latest_assembly_versions
    │   └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1
    │       ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_assembly_structure
    │       ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz
    │       ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_genomic.fna.gz
    │       └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_rna_from_genomic.fna.gz
    └── representative
        └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1
            ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_assembly_structure
            ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz
            ├── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_genomic.fna.gz
            └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_rna_from_genomic.fna.gz

7 directories, 12 files
```

**After:**

```
$ tree
.
└── Aaosphaeria_arxii
    ├── all_assembly_versions
    │   └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1
    │       ├── Aaosphaeria_arxii_GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz
    │       ├── Aaosphaeria_arxii_GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_genomic.fna.gz
    │       ├── Aaosphaeria_arxii_GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_rna_from_genomic.fna.gz
    │       └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_assembly_structure
    ├── latest_assembly_versions
    │   └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1
    │       ├── Aaosphaeria_arxii_GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz
    │       ├── Aaosphaeria_arxii_GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_genomic.fna.gz
    │       ├── Aaosphaeria_arxii_GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_rna_from_genomic.fna.gz
    │       └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_assembly_structure
    └── representative
        └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1
            ├── Aaosphaeria_arxii_GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz
            ├── Aaosphaeria_arxii_GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_genomic.fna.gz
            ├── Aaosphaeria_arxii_GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_rna_from_genomic.fna.gz
            └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_assembly_structure

7 directories, 12 files
```

#### Explanation

The `rename` tool uses the perl substitution operator: `rename 's/old/new/` . This will rename the file by replacing `old` with `new`. The `old` can be a simple string, or it can be a regular expression like it is here.

The regular expression can be simplified to: `.+?/.*/.*` which matches "everything up to the first `/` (`.+?/)`, then everything until the last `/` (`.*/`) and then everything until the end (`.*`). The parentheses are what is known as "capture groups". They allow us to "capture" the matched string and then make it available as `$1`, `$2`, ... `$N` for as many parentheses as you have.

So, here, we actually have `((.+?)/.*/)(.*)`. The first, outer parentheses ( `((.+?)/.*/)`) get everything until the file name, so they will get the path to the file, up to the parent directory. This becomes `$1`. The second, inner parentheses (`(.+?)`) capture the parent directory which becomes `$2`. The last parentheses (`(.*)`) capture the file's name.

Using all of the above, we rename the file to `$1$2_$3`. This is `$1`,the path to the file" (e.g. `Aaosphaeria_arxii/all_assembly_versions/GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1/`), then `$2`, the name of the parent directory followed by a `_` and finally `$3`, the original file name.

---

You still haven't showed us what output you are expecting. If you also want to move the files out of their directories, you can do this instead:

```
rename 's|((.+?)/.*/)(.*)|$2_$3|' */*/*/*fna.gz
```

That will produce the following:

```
$ tree
.
├── Aaosphaeria_arxii
│   ├── all_assembly_versions
│   │   └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1
│   │       └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_assembly_structure
│   ├── latest_assembly_versions
│   │   └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1
│   │       └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_assembly_structure
│   └── representative
│       └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1
│           └── GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_assembly_structure
├── Aaosphaeria_arxii_GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz
├── Aaosphaeria_arxii_GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_genomic.fna.gz
└── Aaosphaeria_arxii_GCA_010015735.1_Aaoar1_rna_from_genomic.fna.gz
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked greatly. Both solutions are usable for me.